# RESTful web service

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

I am implementing a REST service from scratch. I am using Spring + ibatis for the same. 
Now, spring offers REST support using annotations. However, online, I find many tutorials to integrate Jersey with Spring.
My question: Why would one want to introduce extra dependencies by including another framework, that is Jersey JAX-RS, when Spring itself is good?

Comment: JAX-RS is a JEE standard, whereas Springs Rest support is proprietary/3rd party (or whatever one would call it).

Comment: true...but if my application uses Spring to benefit from Spring's IOC feature, would it make sense to introduce extra dependency and include Jersey?

Answer (score 1):

You assume that there's a problem with introducing "another" dependency, which, unless you're developing for some tiny embedded system, there isn't. The added memory footprint, complexity etc would generally be irrelevant.

The decision to use `Spring` or `Jersey` for `REST`v implementation should be one of personal preference and suitability. Pick the one that satisfies your requirements and you're most comfortable with.

Also, using `Spring` for `REST` **will** require additional dependencies itself. If you're only using `Spring` for dependency injection, you won't require spring-web or spring-webmvc, whereas these will be required for `REST`.

Hope this helps